# Additive functionals of simple Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, monte-carlo, concentration-of-measure

Suppose we have an irreducible and aperiodic discrete-time Markov chain on a finite set $S$ with stationary probability $\pi$; denote it by $(X_0, X_1, X_2,...)$. It is known that for every $x\in S$ and every positive function $f:S\to \mathbb{R}_+$
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(X_k) \to \int f d\pi$$
$\mathbb{P}_x$ almost surely. Are there any good resources where the speed of this convergence, namely, the quantity (for an $f\in L^1(\pi)$)
$$ \mathbb{P}_x\bigg( \bigg|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(X_k) -\int f d\pi \bigg| > \varepsilon\bigg)$$
is explored ? I guess this probability decays exponentially for every $x\in S$ in the "ideal" (finite, irreducible, aperiodic) case. Are there any books that answer this question in this simple setting ? I am not looking for generalisations to arbitrary spaces, that most recent papers deal with, but rather a simple, clean and concise statement and proof !

More precisely, I am interested in the case where $f(x)=f_y(x)=1\{x=y\}$ for $y \in S$, since I would like to have exact quantitative bounds on the probability that the empirical measure of the Markov chain deviates from the true invariant probability by more than some small amount.

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/PS_2010__14__435_0), especially Section 1 "State of the art", for a complete answer.

Comment: I guess that [*this paper*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3663.pdf) and some references therein, especially Chapter 3 of [*this*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642033100) would be helpful.

Comment: @SangchulLee How can I see that $\inf_{q \in \Gamma} I(q)$ is **strictly positive** if $\Gamma$ is a set NOT containing an open neighbourhood of the stationary probability vector and **zero** if $\Gamma$ is an open set containing the invariant probability measure ? (based on Eq. (3.1.7) on page 76 in Dembo's book)

Comment: @Nocturne, I am afraid that I can't be of much help as I have just begun studying this topic. :s

Comment: Okay, thank you guys ! I also found [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoap/1028903453) (Theorem 3.3) which solves my question (the only thing is that the constants involved depend on the multiplicative symmetrization of the kernel).